# Laravel 5.8: Controller's route doesn't work correctly

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-5.8

Today I have an issue with a Laravel project (Laravel 5.8). I am building up an intranet page with a Newsboard and some subpages. It is developed on my machine. Windows XAMP Environment with PHP 7.3.4

The problem is my `NewsController,` which doesn't seem to route through the pages correctly.

the urls:

**intranet.test/news/edit/**

**intranet.test/news/123/**

always route to the wrong view, and I don't know why.

**routes/web.php:**

```php
Route::get('/', 'NewsController@index');
Route::resource('/news', 'NewsController');
Route::get('/arbeitsplaene', 'PageController@arbeitsplaene');
Route::get('/apothekenevents', 'PageController@apothekenevents');
Route::get('/kundentermine', 'PageController@kundentermine');
Route::get('/praktikantenbelegung', 'PageController@praktikantenbelegung');
Route::get('/addressbuch', 'PageController@addressbuch');
Route::get('/lieferbedingungen', 'PageController@lieferbedingungen');
Route::get('/qualitaetsmanagement', 'PageController@qualitaetsmanagement');
Route::get('/einekatzenseite', 'PageController@einekatzenseite');
Route::resource('/edvdokumentation', 'EdvdokuController');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

**NewsController:**

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $data['news'] = News::find($id);

    return view('blade.pages.news-edit') -> with('data', $data);
}
```

`intranet.test/news/create` routes to the input mask and gives the right view `[ view('blade.pages.news-create') ]` back

`intranet.test/news/123` routes to output of post 123 and uses the right view too.

Maybe, someone here can help me!

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `php artisan r:l --name=news` you should get all the routes whose name contains 'news' (If you'd rather filther by uri, use `--path` instead).

There, if I'm not mistaken, you'll notice the **EDIT** route has a path like this

```
news/{news}/edit
```

and not

```
news/edit
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you,

you were so right!

When I checked the routes by using "php artisan r:l --name=news" in console i found my problem.

1.) My uri was wrong ! -> news/{news}/edit and NOT news/edit

2.) news/edit routes to the index function and "edit" is not quite an id, so the index-function, which shows the post blows up.

Big thx and sorry for wasting your time ...